# jQuery - select all text from a textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, textarea, selection

How can I make it so when you click inside a textarea, its entire content gets selected?

And eventually when you click again, to deselect it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery: Selecting Text in an Element (akin to highlighting with your mouse)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/985272/jquery-selecting-text-in-an-element-akin-to-highlighting-with-your-mouse)

Comment: @Blender: No, that question concerns highlighting text in an element, not a textarea. The two are quite different.

Answer (score 199, accepted):

To stop the user from getting annoyed when the whole text gets selected every time they try to move the caret using their mouse, you should do this using the `focus` event, not the `click` event. The following will do the job and works around a problem in Chrome that prevents the simplest version (i.e. just calling the textarea's `select()` method in a `focus` event handler) from working.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NM62A/

Code:

```
<textarea id="foo">Some text</textarea>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var textBox = document.getElementById("foo");
    textBox.onfocus = function() {
        textBox.select();

        // Work around Chrome's little problem
        textBox.onmouseup = function() {
            // Prevent further mouseup intervention
            textBox.onmouseup = null;
            return false;
        };
    };
</script>
```

jQuery version:

```
$("#foo").focus(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.select();

    // Work around Chrome's little problem
    $this.mouseup(function() {
        // Prevent further mouseup intervention
        $this.unbind("mouseup");
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: I think it's better to implement this stuff using a separate "select all text" button since automatically selecting the text on focus or click events is realy annoying.

Comment: this fails for me in Chrome, working solution is: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6201757/126600

Comment: @zack: The jsFiddle example in this answer works for me in Chrome. Does it not for you? I agree the answer you linked to is more foolproof.

Comment: @TimDown: you are right, I was being a bit over zealous - actually it does work correctly on 'click', but fails if you `tab` into the textarea - the your other solution works for both cases :)

Comment: Change the above code slightly and it will work like a charm..

`$("#foo").mouseup(function() {`
`$("#foo").unbind("mouseup");`
`return false;`
`});`

you need to refer the textbox without using `this` just refer it with full path.. and it will work..

Comment: @TimDown it was not working for me also.. but after replacing it with absolute reference it worked fine.. i'm using jQuery 1.8..

Answer (score 15):

Better way, with solution to tab and chrome problem and new jquery way

```
$("#element").on("focus keyup", function(e){

        var keycode = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which ? e.which : e.charCode;
        if(keycode === 9 || !keycode){
            // Hacemos select
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.select();

            // Para Chrome's que da problema
            $this.on("mouseup", function() {
                // Unbindeamos el mouseup
                $this.off("mouseup");
                return false;
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 11):

I ended up using this:

```
$('.selectAll').toggle(function() {
  $(this).select();
}, function() {
  $(this).unselect();
});
```

Comment: but I don't know how to check if the text is already selected, so I can reverse the two actions :(

Comment: @Alex: I wouldn't mess too much with this if I were you. Users expect standard behaviour from textareas.

Comment: no, this particular textarea is only meant for copy-paste. all the text I have inside it is a big encryted string which can only be either entirely replaced, or copied to the clipboard

Comment: @Alex: Ah, right. You might want to make it read-only by adding the `readonly` attribute then.

Comment: Consider making the text content of a div.

Comment: @RobG: If it was a div, copy/paste would require more code (and likely a flash-based plugin), rather than using the built-in clipboard capabilities of a textarea.

Comment: @Hollister: No, it's perfectly possible for either user or script to select content within a div. You're probably thinking of copying to the clipboard, which isn't possible in script without a Flash-based library like ZeroClipboard.

Comment: toggle() is now deprecated AND removed

Answer (score 8):

```
$('textarea').focus(function() {
    this.select();
}).mouseup(function() {
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Slightly shorter jQuery version:

```
$('your-element').focus(function(e) {
  e.target.select();
  jQuery(e.target).one('mouseup', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

It handles the Chrome corner case correctly. See http://jsfiddle.net/Ztyx/XMkwm/ for an example.

Comment: Hi, I was tested your code and it's working. Currently, in my situation I am using `disabled` attribute in my `<textarea disabled>test</textarea>`,  but it's not working, so how to fix it?

Answer (score 4):

[Selecting text in an element (akin to highlighting with your mouse)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985272/jquery-selecting-text-in-an-element-akin-to-highlighting-with-your-mouse)

:)

Using the accepted answer on that post, you can call the function like this:

```
$(function() {
  $('#textareaId').click(function() {
    SelectText('#textareaId');
  });
});
```

Comment: Maybe flagging this question as a duplicate might be more useful? It wasn't really your answer, so it'd be better to merge the two questions.

Comment: Agreed -- Though the OP could benefit from the added explanation for her implementation. :)

Comment: That question concerns highlighting text in an element, not a textarea. The two are quite different.

Comment: thanks, I found out that I can do this with `$(this).select()`, I'll use that because it's less code :)