# jquery - field selects all text then unselects it on focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus

trying to figure out why this is happening - I have an input text field and I want all the text to be highlighted when the field receives focus. This happens, very quickly, and then all of the text is unselected. Any idea why this would occur? Here's the code I'm using:

```
$("#permalink").focus(function(){
    this.select();
});
```

Comment: text got unselected automatically or on any action ?

Comment: Maybe it's the same problem that [This Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1269767/1028949) is talking about.

Comment: Looks like your answer lies here

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/480735/select-all-contents-of-textbox-when-it-receives-focus-javascript-or-jquery

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to override the mouseup event on the input element (as mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269722/selecting-text-on-focus-using-jquery-not-working-in-safari-and-chrome/1269767#1269767) - thanks MrSlayer!)

See here for example: http://jsfiddle.net/f8TdX/

Comment: Press tab to after the text has been selected, text remain selected

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue in WebKit. The best option is to use a combination of the `focus` and `mouseup` events. The following comes from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6201757/96100) to a similar question.

```
$("#permalink").focus(function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    $this.select();

    window.setTimeout(function() {
        $this.select();
    }, 1);

    // Work around WebKit's little problem
    $this.mouseup(function() {
        // Prevent further mouseup intervention
        $this.unbind("mouseup");
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input:text").focus(function() { $(this).select(); } );
});
```

[Select all contents of textbox when it receives focus (JavaScript or jQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480735/select-all-contents-of-textbox-when-it-receives-focus-javascript-or-jquery)