# highlight all text in textarea

Tags: javascript

I want to select all of the text inside of a textarea when a user clicks the textarea. I tried `onclick="this.focus()"`, but this didn't do anything. I tried `onclick="this.highlight()"`, but this caused an error. What should I do?

Comment: [2020] modern Browsers have ``setSelectionRange`` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/setSelectionRange

Answer (score 65):

This may annoy your users since it prevents the useful default behaviour of placing the caret where the user clicked and I therefore recommend against it in general. That said, the solution for most browsers is `onclick="this.select()"`.

However, this will not work in Chrome **[UPDATE February 2014: it does now seem to work in recent versions of Chrome]**. For a workaround and general background on this issue, see the following question: [jQuery - select all text from a textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797539/jquery-select-all-text-from-a-textarea/5797700#5797700)

Comment: onclick="this.focus();this.select()" just works fine in Chrome also

Comment: @mars-o: So it does. I wonder if Chrome changed its behaviour or whether I was always wrong about that.

Comment: On Chrome 28, `onclick="this.select()"` does suffice and works!

Comment: `onfocus="this.select()"` works better when using the TAB key, and also allows users to easily control where they want to place the caret.

Comment: @A.Genedy: I agree. The question only mentioned clicking though.

Comment: 2022 here: This works with Chrome for some time now.

Comment: Down-voted for mentioning jQuery on a JavaScript question.

Comment: @John: Heh. I was in 2011, and remain, the last person to force jQuery solutions to non-jQuery questions on Stack Overflow. If you'd looked at the linked answer, you'd see that it provides both a non-jQuery answer (which is relevant to this question) and a jQuery version. Also, please don't "correct" my spelling to American English.

Answer (score 33):

```
onclick="this.focus();this.select()" readonly="readonly"
```

Answer (score 16):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function SelectAll(id)
{
    document.getElementById(id).focus();
    document.getElementById(id).select();
}
</script>

Textarea:<br>
<textarea rows="3" id="txtarea" onClick="SelectAll('txtarea');" style="width:200px" >This text you can select all by clicking here </textarea>
```

I got this code [here](http://javascript-array.com/scripts/onclick_select_all_text_in_field/)

Comment: document.getElementById(id) could be omitted, just pass `this` as a parameter instead: `function SelectAll(el) { el.focus(); el.select(); };`

Answer (score 5):

`onclick="this.focus()"` is redundant, as the `focus()` method is the same as clicking in the textarea (but it places the cursor at the end of the text).

`highlight()` isn't even a function, unless of course you created it somewhere else.

Conclusion: do `this.select()`

Answer (score 3):

To complete other answers perhaps you would like to copy the code/text you've just clicked, so use:

```
onclick="this.focus();this.select();document.execCommand('copy')"
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Saved me time, thanks. :)

Answer (score 3):

Seem to more browsers supporting `setSelectionRange()` than `select()`

**1 way: - Use `setSelectionRange()`**

https://caniuse.com/#search=setSelectionRange

```js
const my_textarea = document.getElementById("my_textarea");

document.getElementById("my_but").onclick = function () {
        
        if(my_textarea.value !== ""){
            

            my_textarea.onfocus = function () {
                my_textarea.setSelectionRange(0, my_textarea.value.length);
                my_textarea.onfocus = undefined;
            } 
            my_textarea.focus();        
            
        }   

    }
```

```html
<textarea id="my_textarea" name="text">1234567</textarea>
<br>
<button id="my_but">Select</button>
```

**2 way: - Use `select()`**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/select#browser_compatibility

```js
const my_textarea = document.getElementById("my_textarea");

document.getElementById("my_but").onclick = function () {
        
        if(my_textarea.value !== ""){
            

            my_textarea.onfocus = function () {
                my_textarea.select();
                my_textarea.onfocus = undefined;
            } 
            my_textarea.focus();        
            
        }   

    }
```

```html
<textarea id="my_textarea" name="text">1234567</textarea>
<br>
<button id="my_but">Select</button>
```

Comment: The .select() method is the most supported: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/select#browser_compatibility.
Your second link to caniuse doesn't show the `.select()` method.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the .focus() as well as the .select() Javascript function to achieve the desired result.

Check the link below for an example:

http://www.plus2net.com/javascript_tutorial/textarea-onclick.php

Answer (score 1):

```js
const elem = document.elementFromPoint(clientX, clientY)
if (elem.select) { // Make sure the method exists.
  elem.focus()
  elem.select()
}
```

You may not want to spend time finding your object.

For example, you have written extensions to [inject scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/#functionality) into the web page.

At this time, you do not need to consider the element ID that you can apply immediately.

#### Example

```html
<textarea rows="3" style="width:200px">"Double click" or Press "F4" to select all text</textarea>
<script>

  let clientX, clientY
  document.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
    clientX = e.clientX
    clientY = e.clientY
  })

  selectAllFunc = () => {
    const elem = document.elementFromPoint(clientX, clientY)
    if (elem.select) { // Make sure the method exists.
      elem.focus()
      elem.select()
    }
  }

  document.addEventListener("keydown", (keyboardEvent) => {
    if (keyboardEvent.key === "F4") { // && keyboardEvent.ctrlKey
      selectAllFunc()
    }
  })

  document.addEventListener("dblclick", (e) => {
      selectAllFunc()
  })
</script>
```