# Selecting/highlighting content of a nicedit editor on focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, placeholder, nicedit

I'm using the inline `NicEdit` editors and I want the entire text of the inline editor to be selected on a focus event for easy deletion, since it contains a placeholder text which should be deleted at all times. It is important for the user experience that the placeholder text is **selected/highlighted** and not just deleted instantly on focus. 
Since this is not a `<textarea>` the jQuery `.select()` method **cannot** be used for this purpose but maybe there is a workaround? 
I appreciate your help.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the link suggested since this question is not about a `<textarea>` but in effect an element with the `contentEditable` attribute. Rather it is a duplicate of [How to select all text in contenteditable div?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797539/jquery-select-all-text-from-a-textarea) which provide the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

I just grabbed the id and used `.empty()`

```
 myNicEditor.addEvent('focus', function(e) {
      var id = myNicEditor.selectedInstance.e.id;
      $("#"+id).empty();
  });
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kellyjandrews/8t3V2/)

Comment: Thank you, however the question was how to select/focus the text (which provides a nice user experience), not just deleting the contents. Sorry if this wasn't clear.

Comment: @EmilØstergårdJohansen It took 3.5 years for you to respond to this? LoLz.

Comment: Haha yeah sorry, I just stumbled over it again and thought I would update it if someone else was looking for it :)