# Why Values in the text field can't be selected by jQuery.select()

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to select values of text fields in a table, using [jQuery.Select](https://api.jquery.com/select/) function. But it's not working. 
Here is it's [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zkcxoyzL/3/): - https://jsfiddle.net/zkcxoyzL/3/

**jQuery Code**:

```
$(function(){
   $("#acquisition_table").on("focus", "[type='text']", function () {
                $(this).select();
   });
});
```

It seems, it selects and automatically deselects within fraction of a second.

Comment: Here is the solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797539/jquery-select-all-text-from-a-textarea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(function() {
    $("#acquisition_table").on("focus", "[type='text']", function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.select();
        // Work around Chrome's little problem
        $this.mouseup(function() {
            // Prevent further mouseup intervention
            $this.unbind("mouseup");
            return false;
        });
    });
});`

Taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/5797700/1139130

Comment: Thanks!. So it's chrome problem.